# Java multithreaded int manipulation doing right

Tags: java, multithreading

the code here is a working prototype of a bigger project but just to show the idea.
i have actions i need to do on int a lot of actions on each int.
i decided that all the actions will be stored in a list and all the ints will be stored in the list
each thread will take 1 action and will run on all the list
but keep getting wrong numbers in the result integerList:

Here is the example code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class ArithmeticA implements ArithmeticManager.ArithmeticAction {

    @Override
    public int arithmetic(int n) {
        return n+1;
    }
}

class ArithmeticB implements ArithmeticManager.ArithmeticAction {

    @Override
    public int arithmetic(int n) {
        return n*2;
    }
}
public class ArithmeticManager {


        private List<Integer> integerList = new Vector<>();
        private List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        public ArithmeticManager(List<Integer> dataFromUser) {
            this.integerList = dataFromUser;
        }

        private void exec(ArithmeticAction arithmeticAction) {

            
            for (int i : integerList) {
              synchronized (tempList) {
                tempList.add(arithmeticAction.arithmetic(i));
              }
            }
            integerList = tempList;

        }
        public List<Integer> invokerActions(List<ArithmeticAction> actions) throws
                InterruptedException {
            List<Thread> jobs = new ArrayList<Thread>();
            for (final ArithmeticAction ac : actions) {
                jobs.add(new Thread(() -> exec(ac)));
            }
            //added start
            for (Thread j : jobs) {
                j.start();
            }
            for (Thread j : jobs) {
                j.join();
            }
            return integerList;
        }
        public interface ArithmeticAction {
            int arithmetic(int n);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<ArithmeticManager.ArithmeticAction> actions = new ArrayList();
            actions.add(new  ArithmeticA());
            actions.add(new  ArithmeticB());



            List<Integer> intData = new ArrayList<>();
            intData.add(1);
            intData.add(2);
            intData.add(3);
            intData.add(4);

            ArithmeticManager arithmeticManager = new ArithmeticManager(intData);
            try {
                List<Integer> result = arithmeticManager.invokerActions(actions);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

}
```

And here is the result looks like the numbers been accumulated:

```
integerList = {ArrayList@656}  size = 4
 0 = {Integer@658} 4
  value = 4
 1 = {Integer@659} 6
  value = 6
 2 = {Integer@660} 8
  value = 8
 3 = {Integer@661} 10
  value = 10
```

**UPDATE**
After moving  List tempList = new ArrayList(); to top class
and adding synchronized :

```
for (int i : integerList) {
                  synchronized (tempList) {
                    tempList.add(arithmeticAction.arithmetic(i));
                  }
                }
```

i still getting :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
    at ArithmeticManager.exec(ArithmeticManager.java:32)
    at ArithmeticManager.lambda$invokerActions$0(ArithmeticManager.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

but when i init integerList to vector

```
private List<Integer> integerList = new Vector<>();
```

all working fine but now i have double sync which is not good
Also i can't not know if the user will initiate the object class with ArrayList or vector
what is the right way to do that?

**UPDATE2**
i converted the loop to be :

```
for(Iterator<Integer> iterator = integerList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
               synchronized (tempList) {
                    tempList.add(arithmeticAction.arithmetic(iterator.next()));
               }
            }
```

now its working just fine , but i don't know for sure its this is thread safe
and will work as expected, do i need to protect the loop also ?

Comment: You should look into using the executor framework, using `Callable<Integer>`s to represent calculations.

Comment: why is that can you explain what it do and what thread do not?

Comment: You can't modify a list while you are iterating it, that's what the `ConcurrentModificationException` means, it has nothing to do with concurrency, threads, etc

Comment: so how can i overcome this? using iterator?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your first `for` loop:

```
for (Thread j : jobs) {
    j.start();
}
```

Calling `start` on a sequence of threads does not guarantee that they will all be executed in the same order in which they were started. Some threads may experience a slight delay before executing, while others may execute instantly.

To make sure they execute sequentially, you must wait for each to conclude before beginning the next:

```
for (Thread j : jobs) {
    j.start();
    // Wait for `j` to die before starting the next thread
    j.join();
}
```

But regardless, in the example you've provided, multithreading actually isn't necessary since all the operations are being done serially anyways.

Comment: Thanks, as i said this is just a concept code, i deal with much larger data 
This code I don't what it to run serially ... i want that mutiple threads do work in parallel 
In you example the thread executes and then wait's right ? this is not the case

Comment: Yes, in the code above each thread waits after executing. If you do end up using parallel processing, just make sure you're okay with the calculations being done out of order.

If you only use commutative operations, like addition, then the order won't matter. But in this example, with addition and multiplication, the order is imperative.

Comment: i see this is just example it can be also strings 
i calculation order is not metter