# Java invoking thread start in same loop

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have this loop that set the job for each thread
my question is how can i in this same loop start the thread, And avoid another loop

```
 List<Thread> works= new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (final action a : actions) {
            threads.add(new Thread(() -> {
                jobMethod(a);
            }));
        }
```

This is i like to avoid :

```
for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
List<Thread> works= new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (final action a : actions) {
  // local var
  Thread tTmp = new Thread(() -> {
    jobMethod(a);
  });
  threads.add(tTmp);
  // and shoot!
  tTmp.start();
}
```

??

;-)

Comment: can i add tTmp.join() in the same loop or it will lose its effect 
as i have allso the loop after :
for (Thread w : works) {
            w.join();
        }

Comment: I doubt so (only if you wish "sequential" processing! ... `start()` is "asynchronous code", `join()` *is "blocking"*) ..so for "sync" - same loop, for "async" - independent loop!

Comment: you mean for async same loop the one im setting the jobs 
and sync ( join ) is in independent loop!

Comment: no, exactly otherwise! :-)) (the join's will still be blocking/joined sequentially, but all threads have the chance to execute/start;)

Comment: hu was reading again your answer you mean the join is in the independent loop if i like async for example i have 2 loops 
first with thread.start and when its done 
i have another loop with thread join()

Comment: exactly! :when you do it in one loop there will be only 1 thread started and joined `|actions|` times... and only finished threads in your list/collection....when you join them "elsewhere" all (`|actions|`) threads execute in parallel... (but joined still in order of the list)

Comment: can you please take alook at this question?  as this question derived from it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884970/java-multithreaded-int-manipulation-doing-right?noredirect=1#comment119994187_67884970

Answer (score 3):

Declare a variable? Seems rather trivial:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> jobMethod(a));
threads.add(t);
t.start();
```

Comment: what about join() can i add it in the same loop

Comment: Obviously not - join() would freeze this thread (just, stop the thread from spawning subthreads). There is no way to make 10 threads, start them, let them run simultaneously, and wait for all 10 to complete, in a single loop.

Comment: @user63898 Re, "what about join()...?" It _never_ makes sense to write code that joins a thread immediately after starting the thread. The entire point of using threads is that you can start a thread, _and then do something else while the thread is running._ You completely defeat that if the code that started the new thread then does nothing but wait for the new thread to finish.