# Java difference between list to list copy

Tags: java, list, arraylist, copy

What is the difference and what is more efficient when copy list to list? For example I have :

```
List<String> firstList= new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();

secondList.add("A");
secondList.add("B");
secondList.add("C");

firstList.add("A_1");
firstList.add("A_2");
firstList.add("A_3");
firstList.add("B_1");
firstList.add("B_2");
firstList.add("B_3");
firstList.add("C_1");
firstList.add("C_2");
firstList.add("C_3");
```

What I'm doing now is:

```
secondList = firstList
```

And it's working fine but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it. As you can see, I replace new data with the old one.

Comment: `secondList = firstList` means that both variables will point to the same object. If you modify `firstList`, `secondList` will be modified as well. Is that what you really want?

Comment: *"im not sure"* **--** as long as you don't know what you need or want, nobody else can give a good advice.

Comment: i want the fastest and safest way to get the data from firstList as firstList is changing all the time 
please check this question as there is the full flow check the exec method 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884970/java-multithreaded-int-manipulation-doing-right?noredirect=1#comment119994187_67884970

Comment: Copying a list in Java has been [covered many times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+list+copy&t=iphone&ia=web). Search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to achieve:

- If you want to **reference** the list, you can do as you did:

  ```
    List<String> thirdList = firstList;
    firstList.set(0, "Z"); // Check this out

    System.out.println(firstList); // [Z, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3]
    System.out.println(thirdList); // [Z, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3]
  ```
- If you want to **copy** the list content, you can do:

  ```
    List<String> thirdList = new ArrayList<>(firstList);
    firstList.set(0, "Z"); // Check this out

    System.out.println(firstList); // [Z, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3]
    System.out.println(thirdList); // [A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3]
  ```